# Wordpress ajax requst returns zero

Tags: ajax

I am using ajax in wordpress , i have done every thing right please update me why i ajax returning zero even if code is correct is there something else in the page which is forcing ajax to return 0. her eis my code for js

```
 jQuery('#seller-shop').on('focusout', function() {  
      var self = jQuery(this);  
      jQuery.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: script.axurl,
                  data: {"action": "wk_check_myshop","shop_slug":self.val(),"nonce":script.nonce},
                success: function(resp)
                { 
                  console.log(resp);
                  if ( response == 0){
                         console.log(response);
                    }  
                }
          });

  });
```

code for php is

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wk_check_myshop',array($mp_obj,'wk_check_myshop_value') );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_wk_check_myshop',array($mp_obj,'wk_check_myshop_value'));
```

Thsi code is inside wp enqueue script hook

```
wp_localize_script( 'marketplace', 'script', array( 'axurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajaxnonce'), 'seller_page' => $page_name , 'site_url' =>site_url() ));
```

Comment: The problem is in the function `wk_check_myshop_value`.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer i had already defined this function

Comment: And where is it? That's exactly the part that is missing in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your Ajax hooked function is:

```
function wk_check_myshop_value() { echo "asdasd";  die;}
```

Try changing `die;` to `die();`

Comment: Hallo thanks for your reply actually there was no bug in the code  the bug was the class object

Answer (score 0):

You can try to return à json response:

```
echo json_encode(array('message'=> 'the message'));
die();
```

Then in the js script you need to parse the json response with var json = $.parseJSON(response);